# Use views to display not voted polls

Tags: views, polls

I'm using polls (from core) to make some enquetes.
Is there a way to use views to display only the polls that a user has not voted yet?

I didn't find anything on google. The only solutions where for Drupal 6. And I'm using drupal 7.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Have you actually tried? Can you, for example, create a view that simply shows all the pools?

Comment: Yes. But it shows the polls as full nodes. It does not give any field that I could test if the user has voted or not. The only filter that I see is if the poll is open or closed.
I've used views with relationships before, and with the poll module I am really lost. =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I tried to use the [hook_views_pre_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7).

```
<?php    
function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    $uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;

    //gets one the poll and return it
        $query = db_select('node', 'n');
        $query->fields('n');

        $subquery = db_select('poll_vote', '');
        $subquery->fields('poll_vote', array('nid'));
        $subquery->condition('poll_vote.uid', $uid);

        $query->condition('n.nid', $subquery, 'NOT IN');
        $query->condition('type', 'poll');
        $query->condition('status', 1);
        $query->range(0, 1);

    $view->build_info['query'] = $query;
    $view->build_info['count_query'] = $query;
}
```

But when I tried to use the pager, it had too many bugs. It felt like a hack. So in the end I used:

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns a page with one not voted poll
 * @return [array] [drupal page array]
 */
function one_poll_page(){

    $page[] = "";
    $uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;

    //gets one the poll and return it
        $query = db_select('node', 'n');
        $query->fields('n');

        $subquery = db_select('poll_vote', '');
        $subquery->fields('poll_vote', array('nid'));
        $subquery->condition('poll_vote.uid', $uid);

        $query->condition('n.nid', $subquery, 'NOT IN');
        $query->condition('type', 'poll');
        $query->condition('status', 1);
        $query->range(0, 1);

        $result = $query->execute();

    foreach ($result as $record) {
      //saves the rendered poll node to the array
      $node = node_load($record->nid);
      $view = node_view($node, 'full');
      $rendered = drupal_render($view);
      $page['#markup'] .= $rendered;
    }

    return $page;
}
```

Because I can then control exactly what the page does.